# How to make go build work with nested directories

Tags: go

In the process of learning go I was playing around with making my own libraries. Here is what I did: in my $GOPATH/src I have two folders: `mylibs` and `test`. The `test` folder has a file called `test.go` which contains

```
package test

import "mylibs/hi/saysHi"

func main() {
    saysHi.SayHi()
}
```

The `mylibs` folder contains another folder called `hi`, which has a file called `saysHi.go` containing:

```
package saysHi

import "fmt"

func SayHi() {
    fmt.Printf("Hi\n")
}
```

So the directory structure looks like this:

- GOPATH/src
- - test
- - - test.go
- - mylibs
- - - hi
- - - - saysHi.go

The problem is that when I try to compile `test` it complains saying

```
cannot find package "mylibs/hi/saysHi" in any of: 
    [...]
    $GOPATH/src/mylibs/hi/saysHi (from $GOPATH)
```

I have deliberately made the directory structure deeper than necessary. If I make a simpler directory structure where I place `saysHi.go` in `$GOPATH/saysHi/saysHi.go` then it works.

But I don't see a reason for why this wouldn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally speaking, your directory name should match the package name. So if you define

```
package saysHi
```

and want to import it with

`import "mylibs/hi/saysHi"`

you should place it in a structure like this:

- mylibs
- - hi
- - - saysHi
- - - - saysHi.go

The name of the `.go` file(s) inside the package makes no difference to the import path, so you could call the `.go` file anything you like.

To explain it a bit further, the import path you use should be the name of the directory containing the package. But, if you define a different package name inside that directory, you should use that name to access the package inside the code. This can be confusing, so it's best to avoid it until you understand where it's best used (hint: package versioning).

It gets confusing, so for example, if you had your package in the path

- mylibs
- - hi
- - - saysHi.go

And inside `saysHi.go` defined,

```
package saysHi
```

Then in test.go you will import it with

```
import "mylibs/hi"
```

And use it with

```
saysHi.SayHi()
```

Notice how you import it with the final directory being `hi`, but use it with the name `saysHi`.

#### Final note

Just in case you didn't know the following: your test file is called `test.go`, and that's fine, if it's just as an example, and not an actual test file for `saysHi.go`. But if it is/were a file containing tests for `saysHi.go`, then the accepted Go standard is to name the file `saysHi_test.go` and place it inside the same package alongside `saysHi.go`.

#### One more final note

I mentioned how you are allowed to choose a different package name from the directory name. But there is actually a way to write the code so that it's less confusing:

```
 import (
    saysHi "mylibs/hi"
 )
```

Would import it from the `mylibs/hi` directory, and make a note of the fact that it should be used with `saysHi`, so readers of your code understand that without having to go look at the `mylibs/hi` code.

Comment: As a go beginner coming from tons of other languages a few of these nuances have been really hard for me to pinpoint / ask questions about. This really helped me get a better idea of how go deals with packages! Thank you so much